# Data Layer Design for interacting with different kind of DBs

Tags: java, design-patterns

Problem:
One of our module is interacting with 3 different redis[different redis will have different redis-KEYS],mongo DB and mySQL. 
How should we design data layer so that in future if we change the database, we need not to change the bussiness layer.

Thought of Desing:

Will have 3 different interface for each kind of DB. For redis, bussiness layer will tell which redis to look for a key. But problem is if we change redis machine, bussiness layer need to be change.

Is there any standard way of handling this situation? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So one redis contains a subset of your keys, other redis have other keys, need to understand why you change between redis, is to get scaling or what business requirement you have. Also need to understand a little bit more why if you change the redis machine your business logic need to change

Comment: An ORM *might* help, however, ideally you would need to stabilize the DB environments, otherwise you might end up with unneeded complexity.

Comment: @Koitoer: This is for scaling.We distribute keys to different redis. I could not figure out a way to tell DAO which redis to look for which keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic of which redis to use for a specific key, is related to Data Access layer not business layer, so Business layer only tell the DAO layer to retrieve a key, and DAO layer will decide which redis instance must be used.

UPDATE:

It seems like a sharding situation: take a look at hibernate sharding (i mean the patterns hibernate used to make better Ideas)(http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-javadev2-11/)

In summary, you can use some kind of **"ShardSelectionStrategy"** (Define such interface) that has **"selectShardIdForNewObject(Object obj)"** that returns a **ShardId** based on input object parameter.

So Every time you want to insert a new object in database, you must pass a ShardSelectionStrategy object to your DAO class that has the knowledge of selecting correct shard for an object, the example in above article is :

```
if (obj instanceof Race) {
   Race rce = (Race) obj;
   return this.determineShardId(rce.getDistance());
} else if (obj instanceof Runner) {
   //Do Something
}
```

So the strategy determines shard ID based on races distance.

Hibernate Also use a **"ShardResolutionStrategy"** when searching for object by its key and pass it to query methods of DAO layer every time it needs to query database.

I hope this information is helpful for you.

Comment: This is exactly I wanted to do. But i could not figure out a way to decide from DAO.

Comment: What is the decision logic?

Comment: Currently at business layer, it know this key is present at which redis, So directly it is called from that machine. Current code is not having any Data layer. Every Db calls are made from business layer. I am interested to separate it into two layer.